# Confused to Cast List in generics method?

Tags: java, debugging, generics, collections, casting

```
    class A {
        private int a;
    }

    public static <T> List<T> listStrToListT(String str) {
        String[] idStrs = str.replace(" ", "").split(",");
        List<T> uids = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String idStr : idStrs) {
            uids.add((T) idStr);
        }
        return uids;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<A> lst = listStrToListT("1,2,3");
        System.err.println(lst);
    }
```

This program don't have any error.But when I debug (in the below picture): `lst` is a `List<String>`.Why I directly assign `List<String>`(right side) to `List<A>`(left side) ?

[image: Debug error Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that generics in Java are only a compile-time thing. At runtime, all generic parameters are erased to non-generic types.

From the compiler's point of view, `listStrToListT` can return any kind of `List` the caller wants, not just `List<String>`. You convinced the compiler of this non-fact by (1) making `listStrToListT` generic and (2) casting `idStr` to `T`. You're saying "I'm sure this cast will work when this runs. Don't worry, Compiler!" This cast certainly smells fishy, doesn't it? What if `T` is `A`...

Anyway, now `List<A> lst = listStrToListT("1,2,3");` compiles, as `listStrToListT` "can return any type of `List`" as mentioned before. You'd imagine that `T` is inferred to be `A`, and your cast in `listStrToListT` would fail at runtime, but that's not what happens.

Now it's runtime, all generic types get erased, making your code look like this:

```
public static List listStrToListT(String str) {
    String[] idStrs = str.replace(" ", "").split(",");
    List uids = new ArrayList();
    for (String idStr : idStrs) {
        uids.add((Object)idStr);
    }
    return uids;
}

// main method:
List lst = listStrToListT("1,2,3");
System.out.println(lst);
```

Note that the cast to `T` becomes a cast to `Object`, which really is just redundant here.

Printing out the list just involves calling `toString` on each of the `Object`s, so no casting is done there.

Note that what "smelled fishy" at compile time, is completely valid at compile time. The fishy cast became a perfectly valid (and redundant) cast to `Object`! Where'd the cast go?

Casts will only be inserted where necessary. This is just how generics work in Java. So let's create such a situation. Let's say in `A` you have a getter for the field `a`, and instead of printing the whole list, you print the `a` of the first element:

```
// main method:
List<A> lst = listStrToListT("1,2,3");
System.out.println(lst.get(0).getA());
```

Well, to be able to access `getA`, a cast needs to be inserted:

```
List lst = listStrToListT("1,2,3");
System.out.println(((A)lst.get(0)).getA());
```

otherwise `lst.get(0)` would be of type `Object`, and `Object`s don't have a `getA` method.

It is at this time that your program will crash.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed explanation. I was confused about the generic method in java.